# Product shown even though it's deactivated?

Tags: magento2, product

**Magento 2.2.3**

I disabled a product using the switch, cleared the cache, re-indexed and checked if it is still shown on the front end ... and it is. I also checked the scope I disabled it in, it's disabled for all stores.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "the switch" being the "status" attribute set to "0" (in catalog_product_entity_int)?

Comment: please confirm are you using any caching mechanism like FPC or varnish?

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal I am using Varnish, but clearing it does not help.